# Objective-C to Swift: Facebook iOS API requestUserInfo method

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

Hi I am trying to figure out how to rewrite this in swift:

```
- (IBAction)requestUserInfo:(id)sender
{
  // We will request the user's public picture and the user's birthday
  // These are the permissions we need:
  NSArray *permissionsNeeded = @[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"email"];

  // Request the permissions the user currently has
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error){
        // Parse the list of existing permissions and extract them for easier use
        NSMutableArray *currentPermissions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"The fucking class is: %@", [result class]);
        NSArray *returnedPermissions = (NSArray *)[result data];
        for (NSDictionary *perm in returnedPermissions) {
          if ([[perm objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"granted"]) {
            [currentPermissions addObject:[perm objectForKey:@"permission"]];
          }
        } // cut cut here

}
```

## EDIT:

I was having trouble trying to get the required data out of the FBGraphObject but figured it out after some further inspection. I have posted the swift version below so that people can just cut and paste it and get on with using swift. Hope it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
@IBAction func requestUserInfo(sender: AnyObject){
    // These are the permissions we need:
    var permissionsNeeded = ["public_profile", "user_birthday", "email"]

    // Request the permissions the user currently has
    FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me/permissions", completionHandler: {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            // Parse the list of existing permissions and extract them for easier use

            var theResult = result as? [String:[AnyObject]]
            var currentPermissions = [String]()
            let returnedPermissions = theResult?["data"] as [[String:String]]

            for perm in returnedPermissions {
                if perm["status"] == "granted" {
                    currentPermissions.append(perm["permission"]!)
                }
            }

            // Build the list of requested permissions by starting with the permissions
            // needed and then removing any current permissions
            println("Needed: \(permissionsNeeded)")
            println("Current: \(currentPermissions)")

            var requestPermissions = NSMutableArray(array: permissionsNeeded, copyItems: true)
            requestPermissions.removeObjectsInArray(currentPermissions)

            println("Asking: \(requestPermissions)")

            // TODO PUT A POPUP HERE TO TELL WHAT PERMISSIONS WE NEED!

            // If we have permissions to request
            if requestPermissions.count > 0 {
                // Ask for the missing permissions
                FBSession.activeSession().requestNewReadPermissions(requestPermissions, completionHandler: {(session, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        // Permission granted, we can request the user information
                        self.makeRequestForUserData()
                    } else {
                        // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                        // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                        println("error: \(error?.description)")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // Permissions are present
                // We can request the user information
                self.makeRequestForUserData()
            }

        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            println("error: \(error?.description)")
        }
    })
}

private func makeRequestForUserData() {
    FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({(connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
            println("user info: \(result)")
        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            println("error: \(error?.description)")
        }
    })
}


// Show an alert message
func showMessage(text : NSString, title : NSString){
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: text, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user